# Recall CallBack(); function when need to use

Tags: android, multithreading, callback

How can I call my `CallBack()` again when I need to use it?

Currently, I'm calling my `CallBack()` by doing this

```
CallBackThreadHome callBackThreadHome = new CallBackThreadHome();
    callBackThreadHome.start();
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but It will eat my RAM consumption?.Because I'm getting a Fatal Error `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000b (code=1), thread 2347 (i.mikee.jti_pos)` .Our device only has 1 GB of RAM that's why I'm very careful on the Threading side.

This is the `callBackThreadHome();`

```
class CallBackThreadHome extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            RFCardInterface.waitForCardPresent(RFCardInterface.CONTACTLESS_CARD_MODE_AUTO, 1, -1);
            if (RFCardInterface.isCallBackCalled &&
                    RFCardInterface.notifyEvent.eventID == RFCardInterface.CONTACTLESS_CARD_EVENT_FOUND_CARD) {

                IDCatcher = StringUtility.ByteArrayToString(RFCardInterface.notifyEvent.eventData,
                        RFCardInterface.notifyEvent.eventData.length);

                IDCatcher = IDCatcher.substring(9, 21);
                IDCatcher = IDCatcher.replace(" ", "");

                Cursor c = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select is_arrived,is_closed from trans_settings order by _id desc limit 1", null);

                if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                    String is_arrived = c.getString(0);
                    String is_closed = c.getString(1);

                    if (is_arrived.equals("0") && is_closed.equals("0")) {
                        SearchEmp();
                    } else if (is_arrived.equals("1") && is_closed.equals("0")) {
                        SearchEmp_isArrived();
                    } else if (is_arrived.equals("1") && is_closed.equals("1")) {
                        SearchEmp_isClosed();
                    }
                    c.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

browsing on Android Studio, There has a function `callBackThreadHome.run()`. Isn't it appropriate?.

Answer (score 1):

Just save the "CallBackThreadHome" in a Global variable and you can reuse it whenever you want.

RAM "eating" doesn't depends of Threading system but only of the WORK you do INSIDE it, however callback doesn't means "Multithreading" but just a method that is called at some specific time from another piece of code.

The SIGSEGV error has a specific meaning, but it's another story/question.

Comment: and when I need to call it? I will call `CallBackThreadHome.start()` or `CallBackThreadHome.run()`?

Comment: We don't know what "CallBackThreadHome" is it. From its name we could suppose it is a Thread, Asynctask or Runnable but without any piece of code (its Class) it's impossible to answer you.

Comment: sorry, I have updated my question. it is a class that extends Thread

Comment: A Thread needs the "start()" method to start it. The Thread will finish its work and then exits. If you want to just run it one-at-time just check if the Thread is "isAlive()" before execute its "start()" again

Comment: Please help me analyze it. As of now I put some if statement and notice that the thread is alive. another question, how can I kill that thread and execute it again. yeah Its logging the thread has exit. but the problem is it still processing leading to fatal error

Comment: I need to call again this thread recursively, because I have a device that reads RF Cards. our flow it after I have tapped the first card, It will close that previous Thread and Open that Thread again. Like a loop. How can I get it?

Comment: You have to read Thread doc from Android Official Guide (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread) about how Threads work. A Thread CANNOT be stopped using a "stop()" method but only by sending to it a "message" in its Handler and wait until it is stopped, OR it finishes when it reaches the end of it's "run()" method (but the amount of time could be variable). It's hard to explain ALL things if you seems not informed about how Threads work......